# error in program while comparing two string in macro in erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have written the macro to compare two string as follow

```
-module(helloworld). 
-export([start/0]). 
-define(macro1(X,Y),{if X == Y -> "True"; true ->"False" end.}). 

start() ->
   io:fwrite("~w",[?macro1("str","str")]).
```

getting the error as follow:

```
Compiling the source code....
$erlc helloworld.erl 2>&1
helloworld.erl:6: syntax error before: '.'
helloworld.erl:2: function start/0 undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macro are not like function definition. The pre processor simply does string replacement. so in your case you have to remove the dot in the curly bracket:

```
-define(macro1(X,Y),{if X == Y -> "True"; true ->"False" end}).
```

Comment: I'd add showing what the code in the question expands to.

Comment: Above change in code ended in error.. helloworld.erl:5: Warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 5 always matches

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. As I said the macro make string replacement so you are now compiling a code where the result of `X==Y` is always true since both X and Y are replaced with "str". The compiler warn you that the second clause of the if will never be executed. If you change in the definition `start() -> io:fwrite("~w",[?macro1("str","str")]).` by `start(X) -> io:fwrite("~w",[?macro1(X,"str")]).`, you will have no warning since every condition can match depending on X value.